# I want one folder on my computer (called the "Airlock") to be accessible to anyone on my network without any password or authentication

Tags: windows, file-sharing

Is this possible anymore? I find that it's the easiest way to share files back and forth at home between me and the wife and kids, but somehow I can't figure out the magic secret. Even giving "EVERYONE", "GUEST", "NETWORK", etc. full sharing rights and security rights to the folder doesn't seem to do it. We're all on the same network and all on "private network".

Comment: Are you on Windows 10/11 Home or Windows 10/11 Professional?

Comment: Windows 11 and 10 mix between the various machines. The one with the file share in question is Win 10 and so is my kid's computer who can't access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sets of permissions to be taken care of.

You have already done the part of the permissions in the
file-system, but you also need to modify the permissions of
the network share.
Both sets of permissions are checked when accessing a file.

This is done in the Properties of the folder, tab Sharing.
Click the button of Advanced Sharing to start the dialog,
click the button Permissions, then add the Everyone group,
and for good measure also Guest or Guests.

For more information see the article
[Share Files and Folders Over a Network in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/111783-share-files-folders-over-network-windows-10-a.html).

Edit : The poster has indicated that
"It seems that some combination of Everyone, Guest, Anonymous, Network, etc has done the job".

Comment: This answer only applies to the professional edition of windows. in home, you only have access to basic sharing

Comment: @LPChip: I just fired up a Windows 10 Home VM, and the Sharing dialog looks identical.

Comment: Maybe its changed. I have Windows 8.1 in my head. I recall you had to change settings in the network center for sharing in order for this to become the same in home as in pro

Comment: I've already done that. Sharing and permissions both are set to EVERYONE and "ALL perms".

Comment: IIRC 'Everyone' does not apply to anonymous guest users by default (though I recall a setting in the secpol/lsp that would include them). try adding Anonymous/Guest users to the share in addition to Everyone, granting them full control

Comment: It  seems that some combination of Everyone, Guest, Anonymous, Network, etc has done the job. If you post it as an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: I added this to my answer.